# xvidcap: Error accessing sound input from /dev/dsp

Tags: 11.10, sound, devices

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm trying xvidcap to record a screencast with audio from the microphone, however it can't record any sound:

```
$ xvidcap --file appo.avi --cap_geometry 700x500-0+0 
Error accessing sound input from /dev/dsp
Sound disabled!
```

Sure enough `/dev/dsp` doesn't even exist:

```
$ sudo ls -lh /dev/dsp
ls: cannot access /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
```

I found a blog post about [fixing xvidcap sound input](http://www.rationalplanet.com/linux/xvidcap-in-fedora-11-error-accessing-sound-input-from-devdsp.html), however if I try the suggestion I get:

```
$ sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss
FATAL: Module snd_pcm_oss not found.
```

So the question is, *how can I create* `/dev/dsp`?

The problem behind the problem is: *how can I record sound from the microphone with xvidcap?* So workarounds are welcome too.

**UPDATE**: I've followed the suggestion of James, and something has improved.

The error accessing `/dev/dsp` is gone, however now I get:

```
[oss @ 0x8e0c120] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
xtoffmpeg.c add_audio_stream(): Can't initialize fifo for audio recording
```

Now when I record `xvidcap` appears in the recording tab of `pavucontrol` and I can choose Audio stream from Internal Audio Analog Stereo or Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo, I tried both just in case, but the video is still mute.

**UPDATE 2**: I found that "Monitor of" is the one to record application sounds, while for microphone, I should choose "Internal Audio Analog Stereo". To rule out other problems, such as with the microphone, I tried with `gnome-sound-recorder` and it works. Actually I jumped on my chair, since the volume was too high! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/dev/dsp` device is part of the obsolete [OSS sound API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System), which has since been replaced by the [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/) API.  The OSS API was removed from the kernel last year (see [bug #579300](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/579300))

Assuming the application doesn't have an option to use the ALSA API, one option that might fix your problem would be to run the application under `padsp`, which will redirect OSS API calls to the [Pulse Audio](http://www.pulseaudio.org/) daemon.  That is, instead of running `xvidcap`, run `padsp xvidcap`.

Comment: Thanks James for the answer, something has improved. I am editing the question with the update, because in the comment wasn't readable.

Comment: I guess the error might mean that xvidcap is using part of the OSS API that `padsp` doesn't implement (e.g. the `mmap` based access method).  Perhaps the answer is to either (a) find some other capture software, or (b) see if you can capture without sound, and then use a video editor to combine the sound track with the video afterwards.

Comment: I'm exploring the second option in fact, besides the sound comes quite noisy, so a pass with audacity is a good idea. I mark the answer as correct, since I think nothing more than this can be done.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea you could wrap commands like this with padsp :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would have been to install osspd to emulate oss under pulseaudio.

```
sudo apt-get install osspd
```

After this my /dev/dsp could be used to capture the microphone for me, like  saving the audio output to file for example.

```
cat /dev/dsp > mic.out
```